# Catch Vue.js warnings for unit testing required properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

We are porting a very large project into Vue.js and would like to thoroughly implement our unit testing suite as we go.

We would like to validate that components are having all their required properties set at creation, my test case looks something like:

```
describe('Input', () => {
  it('fail initialization with no value', () => {
    const vm = mount(Input, {
      propsData: {},
    });

    // expecting above to fail due to required prop 'value'
  });
});
```

The component `Input` is expected to contain a property `value`. I can see via the console warning emitted that it is missing but we would like to catch this in our unit tests. Directly testing this doesn't make much sense but once we have components nesting several components, making sure that each component correctly initialises its sub components is important and this is achieved by assuring ourselves that the above test should fail and be caught failing.

There is no exception raised however, we have had ideas to hook into the `Vue.warnHandler` but this just seems like a lot of work for simply confirming that a constructor works as expected.

Is there a recommended approach to doing this with Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the only way to do this is to hook into the `Vue.warnHandler`

I used a variable and reset it on the `afterEach` hook (Mocha) like so:

```
let localVue;
let hasWarning = false;
function functionToWrapShallowMount(propsData) {
    const Wrapper = shallowMount(Control, {
        propsData,
        provide: {
            $validator: () => {}
        },
        localVue
    });
    return Wrapper;
}
before(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    Vue.config.warnHandler = () => {
        hasWarning = true;
    };
});
afterEach(() => {
    hasWarning = false;
});

it('throws a warning', () => {
    const { vm } = functionToWrapShallowMount({
        name: 'foooo',
        value: 'bad'
    });
    vm.name.should.eq('foooo');
    hasWarning.should.eq(true);
});
```

The catch to this is you cannot use the `localVue` from Vue test utils you must use the `Vue` instance imported from `vue`.